# math random generator

Tags: java, random

//**How to put math random generator in this program.
Thank you :)
**/

//Anyway this program is all about rock, paper , scissor game using JOption utility.
//Can you help me to put Math Random Generator in player 2? because I dont know how to put it.
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class activity13{

```
public static void main(String []args){

    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0;

    String player1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Select an option:\n(r) Rock\n(p) Paper\n(s) Scissor\nPlease input a keyword for player 1");
    String player2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Select an option:\n(r) Rock\n(p) Paper\n(s) Scissor\nPlease input a keyword for player 2");

    String rock = "R";
    String paper = "P";
    String scissor = "S";


    if(player1.equalsIgnoreCase(rock)){

        p1 = 1;

    }
    if(player1.equalsIgnoreCase(paper)){

        p1 = 2;

    }
    if(player1.equalsIgnoreCase(scissor)){

        p1 = 3;

    }
    if(player2.equalsIgnoreCase(rock)){

        p2 = 1;

    }
    if(player2.equalsIgnoreCase(paper)){

        p2 = 2;

    }
    if(player2.equalsIgnoreCase(scissor)){

        p2 = 3;

    }
    if(p1 == p2){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Draw", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
    if(p1 == 1 && p2 == 2){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 Wins", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
    if(p1 == 1 && p2 == 3){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 Wins", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
    if(p1 == 2 && p2 == 1){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 Wins", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
    if(p1 == 2 && p2 == 3){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 Wins", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
    if(p1 == 3 && p2 == 1){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2 Wins", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
    if(p1 == 3 && p2 == 2){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 1 Wins", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Math.random() would be suitable... I think you can optimize this code by combining all winning ifs and losing ifs by using || operator

Answer (score 1):

Random number can be generated by java.util.Random.

To prepare to generate random number : i.e. code to be placed near begining.

```
import java.util.Random;

Random randomGenerator = new Random(); /* create intance of Random */
```

The code to set a random number between 1 and 3 to variable p2

```
p2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1 /* nextInt(3) will return random number between 0 to 2, so add 1 */
```

Very simple.